# numpy: combining multiple arrays from within one array as one array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array that has multiple arrays in it. **array([** array([[n,n,n,][n,n,n]...]), array([[n,n,n,][n,n,n]...]) ...**])**

All the arrays only have numbers and have the same number of columns (eight) but can have different numbers of rows.

How can I make the multiple arrays within the array as one array?

p.s. I'm very new to numpy so pardon if it's a simple question and please explain in very simple words.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `np.ravel(yourArray)` ?

Comment: @M.Massias I just tried it and it doesn't change anything. Thanks though.

Comment: It does not unravel the array in place, you have to do `newArray = np.ravel(yourArray)`

Comment: Can you provide your input in your answer? What is your array's shape?

Comment: Sorry, I'm really new to numpy I'm not sure what you mean by array's shape. Each array has 8 columns and a few hundred rows

Comment: What is the result of yourArray.shape ?

Comment: Now I only have two arrays within the array so the result is (2, )

Comment: And after unravelling it ?

Comment: Can you include your whole original array in your question please ?

Comment: It's too long to post.

Comment: I imported 2 csv files analyzed it and added the data in a list. I have a for loop that analyzes each file separately and then appends the data to the list. I then convert the list to an array but the data from different files are separate arrays within the array. I want to make it all one array

Comment: That is what ravel do. Read the doc in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

As I've posted in the comment you can use numpy's ravel() function:

```
import numpy as np
newArray = np.ravel(oldArray)
```

see the doc about ravel() [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html)